# Prolog gives output several times

Tags: prolog

Here is my code

```
female(queen_elizabeth).
female(diana).
female(kate).
female(charlotte).
female(megan).
male(prince_philip).
male(charles).
male(william).
male(harry).
male(george).
male(louis).
male(archie).

parent(queen_elizabeth, charles).
parent(prince_philip, charles).
parent(charles, william).
parent(charles, harry).
parent(diana, william).
parent(diana, harry).
parent(william, charlotte).
parent(william, louis).
parent(william, george).
parent(kate, charlotte).
parent(kate, louis).
parent(kate, george).
parent(harry, archie).
parent(megan, archie).

child(X, Y) :-
        parent(Y, X).

child(X, Y) :-
        parent(Y, X).

sibling(X, Y) :-
        parent(Q,X),
        parent(Q,Y),
        X\=Y.

cousin(C, Cousin):-
        parent(Parent,C),
        sibling(Parent,AU),
        child(Cousin,AU).

relative(X, Y) :- cousin(X, Y) ; uncle(Y, X) ; aunt(Y, X).
```

For example when I try to use relative fucntion. The output basicly gives what I want but it gives more than 1 time.

As and output I wanna see:

```
Y = charlotte
Y = louis
Y = george
Y = william
```

But the out put is like

```
Y = charlotte
Y = louis
Y = george
Y = charlotte
Y = louis
Y = george
Y = william
Y = william
```

How can I fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you have some missing rules in your code and others which are repeated (you have 2 rules for `child`, one is to be removed), note that any two siblings will have the same parents so the both share their mother and father, so you will probably need to add some constraint skip the second solution.

```
sibling(X, Y) :-
        parent(Q,X),
        parent(Q,Y),
        parent(Q2,X),
        Q2 @< Q,        % both share the same parents
        parent(Q2,Y),   % and Q2 is lexicographically less than Q
        X\=Y.
```

You will still get two different solutions for each pair of cousins as the relation is reflexive (if `A` is cousin of `B` then `B` is cousin of `A`), but they are distinct solutions.

Comment: but this time uncles prints 2 times what I can do for it also
like
Y = william
Y = william

Comment: You didnt post your uncle procedure so I cannot tell the problem, but I believe it would probably be fixed in the same way as in sibling procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than check *both* parents, can just check one:

```
sibling(Lower, Upper) :-
    female(Mother),
    parent(Mother, Lower),
    parent(Mother, Upper),
    % Break symmetry between siblings
    Lower @< Upper.
```

Comment: Those might be half siblings which might be ok. But worse, now its not a relation anymore.